Periodic electric field link operator in QuSpin
I am trying to implement a truncated bosonic Hilbert space as described in Eqs. (15) and (16) of this paper on simulating the Schwinger model. However, I am unable to implement the "periodic wrapping" term using the available operators in QuSpin, i.e. the first term in
$$U_n = |\Lambda \rangle_n \langle -\Lambda |_n + \sum_{\epsilon=-\Lambda}^{\Lambda-1} |\epsilon \rangle_n \langle \epsilon+1|_n \,,$$
where $\Lambda$ is the cutoff and $n \in \{0,1,2,3\}$. The other terms in the sum are easily implemented using QuSpin's ladder operators to construct a Hamiltonian. For example:
N = 4
Lambda = 2
eps = np.arange(-Lambda, Lambda)
sps = len(eps)

basis_b = boson_basis_1d(L=N, sps=sps)

J = 1

Ud_real = [[J, n] for n in range(N)] # Real part of U dagger
U_real = [[J, n] for n in range(N)] # Real part of U 

Ud_imag = [[-1j*J, n] for n in range(N)]  # Imaginary part of U dagger
U_imag = [[1j*J, n] for n in range(N)]  # Imaginary part of U 

static = [["+", Ud_real], ["-", U_real], ["+", Ud_imag], ["-", U_imag]]
dynamic=[]

H_b = hamiltonian(static, dynamic, basis=basis_b)   

However, there doesn't seem to be a way to explicitly link the $+\Lambda$ and $-\Lambda$ states as far as I can tell. Is there a good way to link these two states?
